# XML Serialization question - How to Serialize Element, Attribute and Text from One Object

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm new into XML Serialization using .NET and after working with it for some time I'm quite fuzzled now. I can serialize elements with attributes containing other elements but how can I serialize something like

```
<myElement name="foo">bar</myElement>
```

I use a class for myElement with a XmlAttribute for the "name", but how to refer the value of the XML Element?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[`[XmlText]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx), like so:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
[Serializable, XmlRoot("myElement")]
public class MyType {
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [XmlText]
    public string Text {get;set;}
} 
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType)).Serialize(Console.Out,
            new MyType { Name = "foo", Text = "bar" });
    }
}
```

Comment: 6 years later and it just solved my problem also:). Thanks Marc!

Comment: XmlSerializer throws a Reflection exception if `MyType` is a property.

Comment: @Suncat2000 if you're seeing something unexpected, an example (maybe on "gist.github.com") would really help