# Post Xml with attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-serialization, httpclient

Is is it possible to post by using HttpClient class with properties as XmlAttributes? 
For example we have class:

```
public class request
{
  public string attribute1 { get; set; }

  public string attribute2 { get; set; }
}
```

By using PostAsXmlAsync method.
What attributes I have to use to get request like that:

```
<request attribute1="value" attribute2="value" />
```

I've tried to use in that way

```
[XmlRoot("request")]
public class request
{
  [XmlAttribute("attricute1")]
  public string attribute1 { get; set; }
  [XmlAttribute("attricute1")]
  public string attribute2 { get; set; }
}
```

But got result:

```
<request>
 <attribute1></attribute1>
 <attribute2></attribute2>
</request>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25494252/4172872

Comment: Look if this answer could help you... http://stackoverflow.com/a/797077/4197957

Comment: @levent thanks for your comment, it was helpful for me.